# Convert a class component to functional component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component that looks like this.

```
    class CommentSummary extends React.Component<Properties> {
      constructor(props: Properties) {
        super(props)

        this.onOpen = this.onOpen.bind(this)
      }

      onOpen() {
        const {
          props: {
            question,
            newestChild: { id },
            onOpen,
          },
        } = this
        if (!question) {
          return
        }

        onOpen(question.id, id)
      }
      
    }
```

I want to be able to convert it to a functional component like the code below. I am getting squiggy lines
in the onOpen method below. How can I convert the onOpen method below?

```
    const CommentSummary = (props: Properties) => {

      onOpen() {
        const {
          props: {
            question,
            newestChild: { id },
            onOpen,
          },
        } = this
        if (!question) {
          return
        }

        onOpen(question.id, id)
      }

    }

    export default CommentSummary
```

Comment: `function onOpen() {...`. You have to use the function keyword or assign an arrow function to a const. You're declaring it like it's a class property.

Comment: You also have two functions named `onOpen` which, while not necessarily a problem, would be clearer if they had unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of function component does have this (init reference instance). So, you should declare function as const :

```
const CommentSummary = (props: Properties) => {

    const onOpen = () => {
        const {
            question,
            newestChild: { id },
            onOpen,
        } = props;
        if (!question) {
            return
        }

        onOpen(question.id, id)
    }
}
```